# Overpass-turbo get response as GeoJSON

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-api

In [this tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/tyrasd/45e4a6a44c734497e82ccaae16a9c9ea), the author prefixes the data query with **[out:json]** and adds to the end **out body geom;** which, in my understanding, gives back **osm** data. Then, the author converts the retrieved **osm** data to **GeoJSON** using the next [module](https://tyrasd.github.io/osmtogeojson/). At the end, he uses **.GeoJSON()** function of **Leaflet** to represent data on the map.

Questions:

1. Is there any of way of getting directly geoJSON object from Overpass-API, so I do not need to convert?
2. Is there any better alternative way to have the same result like requesting Overpass-API and showing the results on the map as Markers then the one I provided [above](http://bl.ocks.org/tyrasd/45e4a6a44c734497e82ccaae16a9c9ea)?
3. It seems to me, [this is](https://github.com/GuillaumeAmat/leaflet-overpass-layer) exactly what I was looking for. However, I end up, not being able to have it running. Please any help is appreciated with if you could explain how to install and run it.

Comment: Overpass API doesn’t support geojson. If you happen to use some implementation that can directly use Osm xml, then converting may not be necessary. The third question is too unspecific. In general avoid asking multiple questions here, it tends to get closed quickly.

Comment: For 3) > See this live demo https://rawgit.com/ThomasG77/leaflet-overpass-layer/develop/demo/index.html (forked of official code you mentioned, repo at https://github.com/ThomasG77/leaflet-overpass-layer)

Comment: I decided to stick with just converting osm to geojson.